# Send email to gmail using postfix

Tags: postfix

I am trying to send an email to my gmail using postfix. I am using bash on ubuntu on windows 10. I have tried the website tutorials and was unsuccessful.

main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = smtp.gmail.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = 
relayhost = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = 
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all

relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous 
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem
```

main.rc

```
# Default .mailrc
# Set prompt string
set prompt="& "
# Indentprefix is used for quoting messages
set indentprefix="> "
# Assume 20 lines per screen
set screen=20
# Ask for CC before sending the message
set askcc
# Use '.' to terminate composition of messages
set dot
# Emulate mailx's behaviour
set mailx
# Preserve aborted messages in 'dead.letter'
set save appenddeadletter
# Hold read or saved messages in the system mailbox
set hold
# Display only these headers:
retain from to subject cc reply-to date
# Uncomment and set this to the list of your email addresses:
alt rjphares914@gmail.com
# Set sendmail to the directory mandated by the FHS
set sendmail="/usr/sbin/sendmail"
# End of .mailrc
```

mail.log(too big to paste all of mail.log - this is the beginning of the file)

```
May 31 12:15:02 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/master[196]: terminating on signal 15
May 31 12:15:05 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/master[737]: daemon started -- version 3.3.0, configuration /etc/postfix
May 31 12:15:05 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/qmgr[741]: BA25BA000000036029: from=<rjphares@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>, size=436, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 31 12:15:05 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/local[743]: fatal: bad numerical configuration: mailbox_size_limit = 
May 31 12:15:06 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/master[737]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/local pid 743 exit status 1
May 31 12:15:06 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/master[737]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/local: bad command startup -- throttling
May 31 12:15:24 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/pickup[740]: A1B067000000033AC3: uid=1000 from=<rjphares@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>
May 31 12:15:24 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/cleanup[747]: A1B067000000033AC3: message-id=<20190531161524.A1B067000000033AC3@rjphares.localdomain>
May 31 12:15:24 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/qmgr[741]: A1B067000000033AC3: from=<rjphares@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>, size=422, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
May 31 12:15:24 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/error[748]: A1B067000000033AC3: to=<d@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>, relay=none, delay=0.16, delays=0.06/0.04/0/0.06, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain)
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/pickup[740]: 757166000000033AC8: uid=1000 from=<rjphares@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/cleanup[747]: 757166000000033AC8: message-id=<20190531161544.757166000000033AC8@rjphares.localdomain>
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/qmgr[741]: 757166000000033AC8: from=<rjphares@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>, size=424, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/error[748]: 757166000000033AC8: to=<root@DESKTOP-K50P15B>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (DESKTOP-K50P15B)
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/error[748]: 757166000000033AC8: to=<D@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>, relay=none, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain)
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/cleanup[747]: 814057000000033AC6: message-id=<20190531161544.814057000000033AC6@rjphares.localdomain>
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/bounce[749]: 757166000000033AC8: sender non-delivery notification: 814057000000033AC6
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/qmgr[741]: 814057000000033AC6: from=<>, size=2698, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/qmgr[741]: 757166000000033AC8: removed
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/error[748]: 814057000000033AC6: to=<rjphares@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain)
May 31 12:15:44 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/qmgr[741]: 814057000000033AC6: removed
May 31 12:15:59 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/pickup[740]: D380B7000000033AC8: uid=1000 from=<rjphares@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>
May 31 12:15:59 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/cleanup[747]: D380B7000000033AC8: message-id=<20190531161559.D380B7000000033AC8@rjphares.localdomain>
May 31 12:15:59 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/qmgr[741]: D380B7000000033AC8: from=<rjphares@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>, size=445, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
May 31 12:15:59 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/error[754]: D380B7000000033AC8: to=<ROOT@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain)
May 31 12:15:59 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/error[754]: D380B7000000033AC8: to=<mail@DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.03/0/0/0.02, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (DESKTOP-K50P15B.localdomain)
May 31 12:15:59 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/cleanup[747]: DDAF19000000033AC6: message-id=<20190531161559.DDAF19000000033AC6@rjphares.localdomain>
May 31 12:15:59 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/bounce[749]: D380B7000000033AC8: sender non-delivery notification: DDAF19000000033AC6
May 31 12:15:59 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/qmgr[741]: DDAF19000000033AC6: from=<>, size=2788, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 31 12:15:59 DESKTOP-K50P15B postfix/qmgr[741]: D380B7000000033AC8: removed
'''
```

Comment: Are there any error messages? Can you check `/var/log/mail.log` in the Ubuntu OS for any error messages?

Comment: There is no such file in that directory.

Comment: I also can't send an e-mail to myself

Comment: tell us more: paste commands send and outputs, paste logs too

Comment: I pasted main.cf file.  This the latest site I tried: https://opensource.com/article/18/8/postfix-open-source-mail-transfer-agent

Comment: `/var/log/mail.log` *SHOULD* exist with Postfix.  If it doesn't you'll need to check `sudo tail -n 500 -f /var/log/syslog | grep postfix` when you are sending an email from the system to identify any errors if your syslog utility isn't creating mail.log (which postfix SHOULD be doing)

Comment: Note that WSL is *probably* not the best utility to use for sending mail via PostFix, it'd be best to set up postfix on a dedicated box typically.

Comment: Are you sure that this is right: `myhostname = smtp.gmail.com` ?

Comment: When I try the tail command I get: "tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for reading: No such file or directory" "tail: no files remaining"

Comment: I am trying to send an email through gmail or at least to myself. The site tutorials say to use smtp.gmail.com

Comment: I am hoping someone can help me with this problem